# HTML5 Video tag from PHP Chunked Response, possible?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5-video

is it possible to read a video with the HTML5 Video tag returned by a PHP Service Chunked Response?

What i am trying to achieve is to return a response created from 3 different video files in a single response.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to send the three videos in sequence as separate videos, or combine them into one video on the server?

Comment: Lets say i start the response with 'file1.ogv', and while sending the file to the Client there is a new file created on the server with the name 'file2.ogv' that i would like to add to the chunked response after file1.ogv et finished sending. How will the HTML5 Video tag interpret that?

Comment: There is not a way to add a second video to the stream because you have to know the total size ahead of time. My answer below has an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the video element's "ended" event to load the second video. Something like this should work. You may need to use an XMLHttpRequest to get the url of the new video, etc.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("your-video-element");
vid.addEventListener("ended", function() {
   vid.src = "new video url";
   vid.play()
});
```

If you need the playback to begin immediately you could queue it up ahead of time on another invisible video element to get it cached. This will use more bandwidth while two videos are loading at the same time.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("your-video-element");
var nextVid = document.createElement("video");
nextVid.src = "second video url";
nextVid.preload = "auto";
vid.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    vid.src = nextVid.src;
    vid.play();
});
```

Setting `preload = "auto"` does not guarantee that the browser will preload the video, but leaves it up to the browser to decide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll give it a try. Also, for the 'preload', which browsers actually doesnt support it?

Comment: Look like that Internet Explorer doesnt support it, according to: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_preload.asp

Comment: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/ says IE is unsupported because it ignores "none". In other words "auto" is the default.